# How can I setup a development environment to use subdomains in the Azure emulator like on localhost(IIS) using hosts file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, hosts-file

I have this working in an MVC project on IIS by adjusting the hosts file.

When running an Azure project, I can see some ports getting remapped, not sure what thats doing or how I can set up subdomains, is it also done in the hosts file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working with subdomains is possible in Windows Azure. If you need to map these subdomains to different web applications, you'll need to map these in your service configuration (**hostHeader** attribute):

```
<Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" hostHeader="app.litware.com" />
```

When developing locally, you can do this using host headers like you described. If you want to deploy to production, you'll need to configure a CNAME on your domain.

**Resources**

- http://www.wadewegner.com/2011/02/running-multiple-websites-in-a-windows-azure-web-role/
- http://blog.smarx.com/posts/custom-domain-names-in-windows-azure

Comment: Hi Sandrino, thanks! The subdomains will all be for 1 application (identifying tenant accounts) To confirm I dont' touch the binding and only adjust the headers? I have this working on a non-azure app, so will just need to figure out the port issues etc..not sure if that is clashing, I assume I can run localhost on multiple ports? or create some kind of new dev domain? ....Will check out the links...

Comment: If this is all for a single application, you won't need to add the hostHeader attribute. You can simply work with a CNAME or the c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file. The "port issue" is only present when working with the emulator because the port is already in use (maybe the default website in IIS).

Comment: Stopped the Default Site and restarted IIS (and VS!) and runs fine. Thanks.